# How do I target a looped element by Id with in the same loop?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var numArray = ["One","Two","Three","For","Five","Six"];

for (i = 0, i < numArray.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += <div id='listResult_"+[i]+"'></div><br>;

   var target = document.getElementById('listResult_'+[i]);
   document.addDomListener(target, 'mouseover', function() {
      alert("listResult_"+[i]);
   });
}
```

It only alerts to the last target Id (listResult_5).
How can I target all six individually?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about that function definition; seems like it'd need to capture the value of "i" during the loop. You sure it's not actually looping over the entire array? Seems unlikely-you debug or write you to the console?

Comment: My point was that as written, the value of `i` will not be captured in the function definition--when any of the mouseover functions are executed the value of `i` should be 6--actually a little surprised it's not, but haven't given it much thought.

Comment: TYPO: "For" should be "Four"
Yes it is looping through the entire array and ending with "listResult_Six", which returns alert("listResult_Six") when I hover over it, but not the others. 

Is there a method to target them individually?
Would I have to pass some sort of argument through that function?
Maybe a timer to delay it to capture each pass?

I just don't know how to capture each loop pass...?

Comment: sorry about that. I had to update

Comment: I'm not actually sure why this isn't working (once the closure issue is fixed). It works fine w/ hard-coded divs, but when adding them dynamically, something is funky. [This fiddle explains further.](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/hjW4k) It has something to do w/ adding the event to an added element, but I'm not sure what. There's more JS in the fiddle than necessary 'cuz I was trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (i = 0, i < numArray.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += "<div id='listResult_"+[i]+"'></div><br>";

   var target = document.getElementById('listResult_'+[i]);    

    (function(e) {
       document.addDomListener(target, 'mouseover', function() {
         alert("listResult_"+[e]);
       });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you assign anything to `innerHTML` you **destroy** the elements in there already. Since you are using `+=` you then create new elements… but the event handler you attached to them has been lost. Create and append elements with standard DOM methods instead.

Additionally, `i` is a variable. It will be whatever the last value it as assigned was when the loop has finished.

Get the data from context instead.

Your `for` loop syntax is also incorrect.

`addDomListener` appears to be a Google Maps feature. Use `addEventListener` for HTML.

```
var numArray = ["One","Two","Three","For","Five","Six"];

for (var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
   var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
   myDiv.id = "listResult_"+[i];
   myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myDiv.id));
   document.getElementById('results').appendChild(myDiv);
   // Don't append a line break between block containers. Use CSS isntead.
   myDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      alert(this.id);
   });
}​
```